# Why does my cv2.line shows as rectangular shape instead of a line?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, opencv3.0

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.zeros([10,10,3],dtype=np.uint8)

t2 = (2, 0) 
t3 = (0, 0)
cv2.line(img,t2,t3,(0,0,255),2,8)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

The output is

[image]

I played around with thickness and line type. It doesn't provide a line no matter what!

**EDIT:**
After suggesting on the comment I tried different values which are not at the edge, (4,5) and (2,5).

With thickness=2

```
cv2.line(img,t2,t3,(0,0,255),2,8)
```

[image]

With thickness = 0

```
cv2.line(img,t2,t3,(0,0,255),0,8)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please state what the desired output is, like "I want to draw a line of thickness __ going from coordinate __ to __"?

Comment: I just want to draw a line with the coordinate given in the code. The thickness doesn't matter. Only the shape would be a line.

Comment: Here I want to draw a line from t2 to t3 with any thickness.

Comment: Yes, but that is what is shown in the image. So I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Where do you see a line in the image!! O_O

Comment: Could it be that the problem you have is that you only see part of the line because it is at the edge of the image? Try something like `t2 = (4, 5) 
t3 = (2, 5)` to see the full line.

Comment: Updated the code with more info on the scenario you mentioned @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Yep, so everything is working correctly.

Comment: Please stop toying with me and explain :)

Comment: I honestly don't know what the problem is. Is it that the 2 pixel wide line shows as 3 pixels wide? That would be because it needs to be shown on an odd number of pixels, because the coordinates are the pixel centers. You may use antialiasing to get a smoothed line, `cv2.line(img,t2,t3,(0,0,255),2,cv2.CV_AA)`. Also note that lines have round edges, so the middle is one pixel longer than the edges.

Comment: Set the thickness to **1**.  `cv2.line(img,t2,t3,(0,0,255),1,8)`. Also, your image is so small that when `matplotlib` scales it for visualization, the drawn lines seem to be like rectangles.

Comment: @sgarizvi, can you please make your comment as answer? Because this solves my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `img = np.zeros([10,10,3],dtype=np.uint8)` tells me that your image is 10x10 pixels in size. This way you ain't gonna get a decent line to be shown this way as you request in your code example. You are literately zoomed in approximately 6400x or more. t3 lies left of t2 (that's not logic unless.. Arabic-reading method (right-to-left) is applied) So..lets zoom out at least 2-100 times, and put t2 left of t3 and see what happens!

Approach:

Enlarge your image.. lets say your array goes to 100x100 pixels... then your suggested line by `cv2.line(img,t2,t3,(0,0,255),2,8)` gets zoomed out as well and more into proportion... and **t2** & **t3** become `t2 = (20, 10)` & `t3 = (40, 10)` in other words... it becomes something looking like a rectangle or a line as we all normally expect to see. If you zoom out again and your np array goes to 1000x1000... adjust t2 and t3 coords if needed and then let us know if your problem remains or is solved.

Based on your example I modified it to show what I meant:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8)  # imagesize

t2 = (20, 10)                               # left coordinate of line.
t3 = (40, 10)                               # right coordinate of line
cv2.line(img,t2,t3,(0,0,255),2,8)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

To do yourself: Relax and read my personal note... and most of all..play with the code to see the change in `diagonal line` into something you like to see. Enjoy!

**Personal note:**

> Tahlil: breath in.. and out... my friend... nobody is toying with you! We don't do homework but instead help you to improve you your skills, method of questioning, giving insight in the question you ask and help finding solutions. In return we expect from you that you contribute in helping others as well. Toying gets flagged and removed (almost) by default!
>
> As you stated by **sgarizvi** to answer in answers... I served you an answer and insight how to improve.. can I now get my cookie ... please. Enjoy life and your stay at SO ;-)